# JavaFX ScrollPane not showing ScrollBars until mouse is clicked on the ScrollBar

Tags: javafx, scrollpane, scrollbars

I've got a ScrollPane containing a TableView.  The ScrollBars are hidden until you click the mouse on them.  Since they are invisible you have to guess where to click to make them appear.  It doesn't matter if the TableView has data in it or just the column headers.  It doesn't matter if the ScrollBar policy is ALWAYS.

The vertical ScrollBar displays if you have a scroll mouse and scroll it, but you have to guess where horizontal ScrollBar is and click the mouse on it to make it appear.

How can I make the ScrollBars stay visible in a ScrollPane?

Comment: A `TableView` already implements its own scrolling functionality: there is no need to wrap it in a `ScrollPane`. The scroll pane is probably getting confused because the height reported by the table already accounts for having its own scrolling functionality. Is there a reason you want to wrap the table in a scroll pane? If so, can you post a [MCVE] showing the problem?

Comment: Ahh, so it does.  It would be great if they would add that to the documentation.

Comment: I guess it's implicit in the discussion on table cells, and the documentation on the `Cell` class, which discusses virtualization. (You couldn't have a virtualized control unless it supported scrolling out of the box.)

Comment: Implicit documentation - the next best thing to oral documentation :-).